# Select top 3 most count group by - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, subquery

I have an `sql` statement below which do group based on country names.

```
SELECT COUNTRY,count(*) FROM DRUG_SEIZURE WHERE COUNTRY IS NOT NULL GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

**Result Sample:**

```
Country           Count
-------           -----
America           20
Saudi Arabia      28
China             10
Japan             14
Kenya             10
Pakistan          12
India             11
```

I want the top three max value countries. In the above case i only want:

```
Country           Count
-------           -----
Saudi Arabia      28
America           20
Japan             14
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: order by count and top(3) should do it

Comment: Oracle 11g i am using @Mureinik

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on what RDBMS  you are using:

***SQL SERVER:***

```
SELECT TOP 3 COUNTRY, count(*) 
FROM DRUG_SEIZURE 
WHERE COUNTRY IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY COUNTRY
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

***MySQL:***

```
SELECT COUNTRY, count(*) 
FROM DRUG_SEIZURE 
WHERE COUNTRY IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY COUNTRY
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

***Oracle:***

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT COUNTRY, count(*) 
  FROM DRUG_SEIZURE 
  WHERE COUNTRY IS NOT NULL 
  GROUP BY COUNTRY
  ORDER BY count(*) DESC
) mr
WHERE rownum <= 3
ORDER BY rownum;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT   COUNTRY,count(*) 
        FROM     DRUG_SEIZURE 
        WHERE    COUNTRY IS NOT NULL 
        GROUP BY COUNTRY
        ORDER BY 2 DESC)
WHERE  rownum <= 3;
```

Comment: whats this Order By `2`?

Comment: That is ordering by the second field in the SELECT which would be `count(*) `.

Comment: Yup, @Linger beat me to it. Kudos.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TOP 3 COUNTRY, COUNT(*) 
FROM DRUG_SEIZURE 
WHERE COUNTRY IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY COUNTRY
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Thankyou this post and above post helped me.

Comment: This is one of those sad cases where the first answer was subsequently invalidated by changing the tags on the question (this being SQL Server syntax instead of Oracle as the question is now tagged).

Comment: Tom's answer was posted before user3400389 specified the RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

See:

http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-limit

for a good overview on how to limit result set according to standard, and in a number of different DBMS.